# Under maintenance page if Heroku goes down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am using Heroku and I am worried that if it goes down, I want to inform the users.

Where should I place my static `under_maintenance.html` page, so that I can tell Heroku to point there if the status of the app is under maintenance?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In short

```
`heroku config:set MAINTENANCE_PAGE_URL=http://s3.amazonaws.com/your_bucket/your_maintenance_page.html`
```

Keep in mind that you should host this static page outside of heroku.

Reference
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode